# Problems with uploading to Arduino Uno from Linux Mint 19

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, linux-mint

Using Linux Mint 19.1 Tessa and trying to upload to Arduino UNO.
Have set the IDE as per [official documentation](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Linux) of Arduino.
Have set the bord as `Arduino UNO` and the port as `/dev/ttyACM0`
Once in a while, it works, but 2 times out of 40.
My steps to upload the new code are:

1. run `arduino` IDE (*same with root - sudo*)
2. in opened IDE, load the code
3. press the reset button on the Arduino board
4. press the upload button in IDE

Most of the time the result is either:

`avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding`

or

`avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "/dev/ttyACM0": Device or resource busy`

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: try other USB cable

Comment: I found a way. Basically, when I'm connecting the UNO to my PC and press the `Reset` button on it, there is a time period when UNO gets ready for resetting and resetting by itself. During that period if I try to upload it returns `device or resource busy`. If I upload later, like a couple of minutes later, it will show `programmer is not responding`. So there is a small gap between these two. So i just keep trying to upload right after pressing reset untill it succeeds  :)

Comment: the Uno should reset with auto-reset on new USB connection. is the auto-reset disabled on your Uno?

Comment: I haven't disabled it. But thanks, I will check out the board to see. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, and solved it by closing an old Arduino IDE window which was using the serial monitor.
Close it and try again to upload.